# inconsistent behaviour in WebLogic when loading classes from a WAR exposing WebServices (Servlet 3.0) within an EAR

Tags: java, web-services, classloader, weblogic12c

I'm facing a really weird problem with the deployment of an EAR package in Weblogic 12c (12.2.1.0.0).
First of all, we need to use a very old and specific library, but this library has a problem on a class, so we rewrote the same class in a different jar and putting it in the class-path just before the buggy one forced the classloading order so that at runtime our version is loaded earlier and everything work as expected.
Unfortunately, according to [the Oracle's documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/wls/WLPRG/classloading.htm#WLPRG282), Weblogic does not work as expected with the Class-Path entry within the MANIFEST.MF file when deploying a simple WAR.
To make it work, I need to repackage my application in the following way:

```
EAR
  + libz
  + META-INF
  + ws-webapp.war
```

My "libz" folder contains all the dependencies, incliding the legacy jar and the patching one. 
The MANIFEST.MF within the ws-webapp defines my Class-Path, including the prefix "libz" and it seems to work fine.

The weirdness happens when I try to define a webservice using annotations.
Suppose I have a class named Foo, that's in the legacy library, **and** is one of the classes I need to patch.

The following code works perfectly fine, the code compiles, the EAR is deployed, the webservice runs and the result is the expected, i.e. I receive the toString() as implemented in the patched class:

```
@WebService(serviceName = "MyWebService")
public class MyWebService {

    @WebMethod(operationName = "Foo")
    public void foo() {
        System.out.println(new Foo());
    }
}
```

On the other side, if I simply create a method returning a Foo object, like in the following example:

```
@WebService(serviceName = "MyWebService")
public class MyWebService {

    @WebMethod(operationName = "Foo")
    public void foo() {
        System.out.println(getFoo());
    }

    private Foo getFoo() {
        return new Foo();
    }
}
```

I am not even able to deploy the EAR, because Weblogic returns an exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.legacy.Foo
```

I tried to play around with the "prefer-web-inf-classes" in the weblogic deployment descriptor, but this approach doesn't work because I need to keep the classloading order for the reason mentioned above and I can't force weblogic to use the one in the war's Manifest.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution to my problem.
The strange behavior is given by jaxws. Since it is a native java library, Weblogic loads it with the system class loader. When my objects are declared within a method, they're naturally loaded ad runtime. The methods signatures, instead, are loaded at deploy time, therefore, since my libraries are defined within the Manifest of the war, they're not "seen" yet, so the ClassNotFoundException.

Another mistake, was defining the custom library folder within the ear file:

```
EAR
+ libz
+ META-INF
+ ws-webapp.war
```

Long story short: I renamed **libz** to **lib** and Weblogic loads the ear in the "standard way", that is looking for the application libraries within the well known folders.
Then I completed as follows:

1. I set up the war project as described in the Oracle documentation, in order to 
   look for the libraries in the lib folder near the war
2. I configured maven(*) to add all the dependencies to the MANIFEST.MF but **not** in the WEB-INF/lib of the war
3. Finally, I added in the Weblogic.xml deployment descriptor the directive to load libraries from the war first, through the element "**prefer-web-inf-classes**".

The prefer-web-inf-classes in the deployment descriptor is important to instruct Weblogic that we want to use the Class-Path entry described in the MANIFEST.MF 
To tell maven to include the libraries in the MANIFEST but not in the WEB-INF/lib, simply add

```
<optional>true</optional>
```

to each dependency.

Comment: so does your war file contain a MANIFEST.MF or are you referring to this file within META-INF which is at the same level as the war ? I am confused by your points #1 and #2